# Updating weights via backpropagation

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, backpropagation

How exactly are the theta parameters (AKA weights) updated after the errors have been calculated?

I do not know how to implement LaTeX here so I will display the pictures (from Andrew Ng's machine learning course) of what I know has to be done before theta/weights can be updated.

What is done next using the calculted delta "accumulator" matrix, or rather, how do I apply the accumulator matrix to update my weights?

On the course Andrew uses the computations shown below to be fed into an optimizer such as fminunc and do the parameter updating automatically, but I want to know clearly how to do the updating which is hidden away by the optimizer. I want to know how to compute the updating manually.

Do I simply apply New Weights = Old Weights - (learning-rate x D matrix)(from step 5 below)?

[image]
[image]

Comment: What is a theta parameter?

Comment: @Colonder The theta parameter is another term for a weight, so the theta matrix simply stores the weights for each node of every layer

Comment: And what is the issue exactly? The formula seems correct

Comment: @Colonder I want to know how to proceed using the computed results in order to update my weights